# completablefuture runasync in foreach loop

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I have defined completablefuture runasync() task in foreach loop.

I have a requirement to insert records in nosql db and need to update the same inserted records as 'processed' in sql db(migrating data from sqldb DB2 to nosql mongodb).

To achieve this, I have defined mongo insertion process in runasyn() and function to update data as processed in db2 in thenAccept() (once check the code snippet)

So the problem is after each record insertion in mongo I am keeping inserted record in list and trying to update entire list in db2 in one shot, but its not behaving like that, for every insertion in mongo its hitting db2 for every record update but this is not feasible approach when processing thousands of records. My expectation is first to have the list of mongo inserted records and update those list of records as 'processed'in db2 in one shot. Is there any possibility for this approach? (I aware both mongo insertion and db2 update defined inside foreach loop but I want mongo should complete insertion for all entries then need to update db2 for entire mongo inserted list in one shot )
or if I able to return list of inserted records from mongoProcess atleast.

Code snippet:

```
unprocessedList.foreach(entry-> {
Completablefuture <Void> cf= Completablefuture.runAsync(() -> {
mongoHelper.processInMongo(entry, getObj(entry)) } , executor). thenAccept ( 
updateInDb2 ( entryList)) });
```

Comment: your question is ... highly confusing and hard to read, could you please try to clean it up? You might want to ask someone who speaks english to help you articulate your actual question

Comment: so you insert each record separately in mongodb. Why don't you do it in one batch? Then you would not need to use Completablefuture at all.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov we are validating an indicator in each record, based on that we are either updating or inserting data in mongo, so batch insertion is not possible here.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you want to finish all insertions and only then do one update.
you can change your code to use Promises (i'm not too familiar with java ones myself) so here is a "basic" solution scheme to your problem.

note you should use  [atomicInterger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for the counter variable as ++ is not atomic and will not work 100% of the times otherwise

```
function x (count, expected) {
 if(count == expected) {
    updateInDb2 ( entryList)) 
   }
}

counter = 0:

unprocessedList.foreach(entry-> {
    Completablefuture <Void> cf= Completablefuture.runAsync(() -> {
    mongoHelper.processInMongo(entry, getObj(entry)) } , executor).thenAccept(
   counter++;
   x(counter, unprocessedList.length);
 });
```

as i said im not too familiar with java promises but a better solution would be one in the form of:

await promise = insert all mongo documents
promise fulfilled then update list